# Press the 'enter' key to move forward

Tags: c++, keyboard-input

I would like my program to only move forward when the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed (not any other key).

This is what I have so far:

```
while (getline(in, line) )   {

                cout << line << endl;;

                cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ignore` accepts a delimiter argument:

```
basic_istream& ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() );
```

You can use it like this:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: `while(getchar()=='\n');` WTF